# How to increment the index of an object in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

I have just recently picked up java and am working on my own implementation of the knight's tour problem using a 2d ArrayList. I do not know if this is possible, but is there a way to increment the index of an object in a 2d ArrayList? Or any other type of array?

Here I have my knight initialized to 1, and I have set board[0][0] to my knight.

```
int knight = 1;

board[0][0].add(knight); // board[0][0] is now 1
```

So now my knight is currently at the upper left hand square of the board (i.e. `board[0][0]`)
And now I want to do something like this `board[0]+=1[0]+=2 = knight` to set my knight's position to `board[1][2]`, but I am not sure how to do this.
I want to do this in a way so that when my knight is on a different square it will still work.

Here is my ChessBoard class:

```
public class ChessBoard {

ArrayList[][] board;

public ChessBoard() {
    this.board = new ArrayList[8][8];
    board[0][0] = new ArrayList();
    board[1][0] = new ArrayList();
    board[2][0] = new ArrayList();
    board[3][0] = new ArrayList();
    board[4][0] = new ArrayList();
    board[5][0] = new ArrayList();
    board[6][0] = new ArrayList();
    board[7][0] = new ArrayList();
}
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: `board[0][0] = 0; board[1][2] = knight;`.

Comment: **most confusing syntax ever** ArrayList[][] board;

Comment: Why not `int[][] board`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly declare a 2d string array like:

```
String [][] board = new String [8][8];
```

But why not create a board class:

```
public class Board {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public void incrementX () {
        x++;
    }
    ...
}
```

Or something like that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think this will be more like what I am wanting.

Comment: i wont go with this because the board actually isnt moving, you want your knight to change positions, not the board.

Comment: @luisdurazoa that's a fair point - and I would agree with you if the question was how to develop a chess game.  But, since it's around the Knight's tour problem, which traditionally isn't solved by brute force but by other approaches, such as divide and conquer, which changes the board size.  I wasn't modeling the knight, but the board.

Comment: I will try this problem right away, i was trying to model a real chessboard, then realized it is something completely different.